# Deploy multiple webapps from a single pipeline and repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently my repo has two node projects: `./server` and `./client`

I want to run the pipeline to install both dependencies, and then when deployed to the 'single' agent/vm/subdomain, i want to be able to run both.

```
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool: 
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:            
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: tomyserver'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'cd server; yarn run startnode;'
```

Ive copied the whole repo artifact over to the vm and currently only deploy for the server. It is a single setup as above. I would imagine extending the startUpCommand to be
`'cd server; yarn run startnode;'cd ../client; yarn run start` can be done better. How would i do it for both the node express server and the react app?

Ideally i can start both apps and they will be run on the domain like this:

- thisproject.domain.com/app
- thisproject.domain.com/project

Really not sure on the best approach, i'm quite amateur at pipelines in azure like this.

Comment: Hi @mewc did you check out below script, how did it go? Please let me know if there is any question

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Kudu api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) to execute the `cd ../client; yarn run start` command.

In order to call kudu api, you need to add a azure powershell task after AzureWebApp task to run below inline script.

After your artifacts is deployed to azure web app. You can check your azure web app deployed environment by visiting `https://{{YOUR-APP-NAME}}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/{{FOLDER}}`.

you can check your azure web deployed folder by visiting above site and decide `$apiCommand` executing dir. It is usually `dir="D:\home\site\wwwroot"`.

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript' 
  inputs:    
    azureSubscription: '<...>'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $ResGroupName = "<..>"
     $WebAppName = "<..>"

     # Get publishing profile for web application
     $WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $ResGroupName
     [xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp

     # Create Base64 authorization header
     $username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
     $password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
     $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
     $apiBaseUrl = "https://$($WebApp.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"

     $apiCommand = @{
              command = 'powershell.exe -command "cd client; yarn run start"'
              dir="D:\home\site\wwwroot"
         }
     Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiBaseUrl -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $base64AuthInfo";"If-Match"="*"} -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $apiCommand)

    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

  enabled: false
```

Above script gets the username and Password from the Publish Profile file of your Azure Web App. The username and password is needed to call kudu api to execute command. The username and password can also be retrieved on azure portal ( download the Publish Profile file of the Azure Web App on azure portal).

The apicommand in above script instructs the command to execute in azure web app deployed environment. In above example the command will execute `cd client; yarn run start` to start client app.

Please check here for more information about [kudu api examples](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-to-azure-platform-as-a-service-websites-using-kudu-rest-apis/)